# How to lock screen orientation in Dart

Tags: mobile, dart

How to lock screen orientation?

Tried this code, but seems, that I use it wrong... Cause it doesnt work on my android smartphone...

```
  window.screen.orientation.lock(window.screen.orientation.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that in Dart.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6381

The issue also contains links how to do that in platform native code.
You can make such native available to Dart using a plugin https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin